# Codeigniter check if one columns items present in another column

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to figure out how to check if any of one column's items present in another column in Codeigniter....

I have Bike,Car,Bus in a column(Vehicles) in a table1...
I also have Bus,Helicopter,Ship,Car in a column(Interested) in table2..

How to check if any of table2 interested column's items present in table1 vehicles column...

I tried like this...

```
$query = $this->db->get('table2');
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{   
    $a = explode(',', $row->interested);
    $this->db->where_in('Vehicles', $a);
    $query = $this->db->get('table1');
    foreach($query->result() as $row2)
    {
        echo $row2->ID;
    }
}
```

Could it be done ?? Please Help me... Thanks in advance....

Comment: I see you use `explode`. Do `interested` field have text data type?

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to help you without seeing the tables and how you are relating one to the other (such as user_id).

What you should do is two queries. One query to get the data from table 1 of the vehicles you are interested in. Then run through the result set and create a simple array of those vehicles in php. Then do a second query using where_in to select all the rows that are in the chosen vehicles array.

Your method is bad because the number of db queries depends on the size of the result set of your first query. You might find your code trying to do hundreds of database queries.

If you show a diagram of your tables, I could write some example code for you.

Here are the docs for where_in: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in